# Callback Not working in Javascript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var test_output_url = results[res].reference_test_cases[0].automation_tests[0].test_outputs[0];

$.when(self.callTestOutputData(test_output_url)).done(function(testOutputResponse) {
  var parameters = JSON.parse(results[res].reference_test_cases[0].automation_tests[0].parameters);
  obj.bu = parameters["Home|Oracle Procurement Cloud|Edit Requisition Preferences|Requisitioning BU"];
  obj.po = "NA";
  obj.receipt_no = "NA";
  obj.category = parameters["Home|Oracle Procurement Cloud|Category"];
  obj.supplier = parameters["Home|Oracle Procurement Cloud|Create Request|Supplier_LIST"][0];
  obj.supplier_site = parameters["Home|Oracle Procurement Cloud|Create Request|Supplier Site_LIST"][0];
  obj.supplier_contract = parameters["Home|Oracle Procurement Cloud|Create Request|Supplier Contact_LIST"][0];
  obj.requistion_number = testOutputResponse.value;
console.log(obj);
self.excelTmpArr().push(obj);
});
```

I have defined the function callTestOutputData  just below this but this is not called only. Can anyone help me in fixing this?

```
self.callTestOutputData = function (endPointTestOutput) {
            let payload = {};
            payload.Endpoint = endPointTestOutput;
            payload.BeforeSend = function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('guest:XXX'));
            };
            payload.OnSuccess = function (response) {
            };
            payload.OnError = function (data) {
                showMessage(self.messages, data.status, data.statusText, 'error');
            };
            return getData(payload);
        }
```

This is the getData module for the function call

```
var getData = function (asyncData) {
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: asyncData.Endpoint,
        data: asyncData.json,
        beforeSend: asyncData.BeforeSend,
        success: asyncData.OnSuccess,
        error: asyncData.OnError
    });
    return xhr;
};
```

I have made these changes. Will this work now?

Comment: Move the `callTestOutputData` above `$.when`

Comment: Does `callTestOutputData` return a promise?

Comment: The last two lines should be inside the callback function. Otherwise you execute them before the callback function fills in `obj`.

Comment: @Barmar, I added the definition of callTestOutputData

Comment: The argument to `$.when()` should be a promise (or jQuery `Deferred`).

Comment: I don't understand that function. It never sends the AJAX request.

Comment: @Barmar, I have made some edits. Not sur eif the response will be caught inside testOutputResponse

Comment: You need `return getData(payload);`

Comment: You never set `payload.json` in `getData()`.

Comment: @Barmar, I made the change but in the UI , whenever the function is called it is stuck, keeps loading.

Comment: You're not parsing the JSON in `testOutputResponse`. You ccan use `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.ajax()` call to make that happen automatically.